# Citation sections are bold, biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

I am using a custom biblatex template for my references. For some reason, the conjunction "and" is always bold. I want to make all my author name related citation sections plain.

Here are screenshots:

Reference list:
[image]

Intext citation:
[image]
My code looks the following way:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{skip=0pt, textfont=it, justification=centering, width=0.8\linewidth} %caption parameters

\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    round-mode          = places, % Rounds numbers
    round-precision     = 2, % to 2 places
}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=ext-authoryear-comp, giveninits, uniquename=init, maxbibnames=999,
urldate=long,
innamebeforetitle, articlein=false,
]{biblatex}
\DeclareDelimFormat*{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat[textcite]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareDelimFormat{andothersdelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\compcitedelim}{\multicitedelim}
\makeatletter
\AtEveryCitekey{\global\undef\cbx@lastyear}
\makeatother
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareFieldFormat{biblabeldate}{#1}
\DeclareFieldAlias{biblistlabeldate}{biblabeldate}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareDelimFormat{translatortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat
[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
{title}{#1\isdot}
\newcommand*{\mkbiburlangle}[1]{<#1>}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{Available at\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{Visited:\space#1}}
\renewcommand*{\jourvoldelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\volnumdatedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{issuedate}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{\url{https://doi.org/#1}}

\addbibresource{businessreport.bib}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{document}

Sentence with citation \parencite{Mullins2016}.    

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And my bib file would look like:

```
@book{Mullins2016,
address = {Harlow},
author = {Mullins, Laurie J. and Christy, Gill},
edition = {11th},
isbn = {978-1-292-08848-8},
publisher = {Pearson Education Limited},
title = {{Management and Organisational Behaviour}},
year = {2016}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are loading `babel` but setting no language, so `biblatex` gets disrupted for not knowing the language of the document, and what you see are the bibstrings names, not their values (thus they are typeset bold). If you need `babel` for English, set the language with `\usepackage[english]{babel}`.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=ext-authoryear-comp, giveninits, uniquename=init, maxbibnames=999,
urldate=long,
innamebeforetitle, articlein=false,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{businessreport.bib}

\begin{document}

Sentence with citation \parencite{Mullins2016}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Everything sorted.

Comment: @AleksejsNarusevics If this answer answered your question, please consider accepting it to show that the problem is resolved. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.